# SharePoint 2016: Summary Link WebPart Issue

Tags: web-part, 2016, migration

After migration from 2013 to 2016, we are facing a weird issue.

While a visitor group member log into portal, they are facing issue with summary link webpart (in all the pages wherever summary i). The webpart throws error **"unable to display this web part. to troubleshoot the problem open this web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation - Compatible HTML..."**

But, If we once log in with admin account (or) user with full control, all the visitor group members will be able to view the webpart. Even if the system account logs out they will be able to view the webpart without any issue. So due to this, every day early morning we are forced to log in with admin account and sign out.

[image]

**Log File Reference**

Entering Monitored Scope (Request (GET:https://insight.company.com/Style%20Library/XSL%20Style%20Sheets/ItemStyle.xsl)). Parent=None    e62f2e9f-b87d-50ed-c97e-cbaf84e5b195

Looking up SPSite by ID 872d2fa4-de04-420e-a26e-e14d3748c0e0 in memory. e62f2e9f-b87d-50ed-c97e-cbaf84e5b195

Name=Request (GET:https://insight.company.com/Style%20Library/XSL%20Style%20Sheets/ItemStyle.xsl)   0d302e9f-983b-50ed-c97e-cef24af11193

SPRequestModule.BeginRequestHandler End 0d302e9f-983b-50ed-c97e-cef24af11193

Web Content Management  Publishing  aytib   ObjectCachePerRequest Global:True, Enabled:False    0d302e9f-983b-50ed-c97e-cef24af11193

SPRequestModule.PostAuthenticateRequestHandler Begin    0d302e9f-983b-50ed-c97e-cef24af11193

Authentication Authorization    agb9s   Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=False, UserIdentityName=, ClaimsCount=0  0d302e9f-983b-50ed-c97e-cef24af11193

Runtime ajd6k   Value for isAnonymousAllowed is : False 0d302e9f-983b-50ed-c97e-cef24af11193

Runtime ajd6l   Value for checkAuthenticationCookie is : True   0d302e9f-983b-50ed-c97e-cef24af11193

Claims Authentication   af32k   Claims Windows Sign-In: Sending 401 for request 'https://insight.company.com/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/ItemStyle.xsl' because the user is not authenticated and resource requires authentication.  0d302e9f-983b-50ed-c97e-cef24af11193

Sending HTTP response 401 - text/plain:401 UNAUTHORIZED.    0d302e9f-983b-50ed-c97e-cef24af11193

SPRequestModule.PostLogRequestHandler Begin 0d302e9f-983b-50ed-c97e-cef24af11193

SPRequestModule.PostLogRequestHandler End   0d302e9f-983b-50ed-c97e-cef24af11193

SPRequestModule.EndRequestHandler Begin 0d302e9f-983b-50ed-c97e-cef24af11193

Looking up SPSite by ID 872d2fa4-de04-420e-a26e-e14d3748c0e0 in memory. 0d302e9f-983b-50ed-c97e-cef24af11193

SPRequestModule.PreSendRequestHeaders End   0d302e9f-983b-50ed-c97e-cef24af11193

Micro Trace Tags: 0 avwhy,0 nasq,0 az4z8,0 avwhz,0 aytib,0 avwh6,0 agb9s,0 ajd6k,0 ajd6l,0 af32k,0 b6p2,0 avwia,0 avwib,0 avwic,0 az4z8,0 avwh5 0d302e9f-983b-50ed-c97e-cef24af11193

Sending HTTP response 302 for HTTP request GET to https://insight.company.com/Style%20Library/XSL%20Style%20Sheets/ItemStyle.xsl    0d302e9f-983b-50ed-c97e-cef24af11193

Could not get SPWeb so could not get user key.  0d302e9f-983b-50ed-c97e-cef24af11193

No user key for user in request usage.  0d302e9f-983b-50ed-c97e-cef24af11193

Leaving Monitored Scope: (Request (GET:https://insight.company.com/Style%20Library/XSL%20Style%20Sheets/ItemStyle.xsl)) Execution Time=2.42444456472394; CPU Milliseconds=2; SQL Query Count=0; Parent=None 0d302e9f-983b-50ed-c97e-cef24af11193

SPRequestModule.EndRequestHandler End   0d302e9f-983b-50ed-c97e-cef24af11193

Sending HTTP response 401 - text/plain:401 UNAUTHORIZED.    0d302e9f-983b-50ed-c97e-cef24af11193

SPApplicationAuthenticationModule.IsBearerChallengeRequested: Return 'False'.   0d302e9f-983b-50ed-c97e-cef24af11193

Web Parts   89a1    High    Error while executing web part: System.Xml.Xsl.XslLoadException: XSLT compile error. An error occurred at (1,462). ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()     at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetNonFileStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)     at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WSSXmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)     at System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.XsltLoader.CreateReader(Uri uri, XmlResolver xmlResolver)     at System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.XsltLoader.LoadStylesheet(Uri uri, Boolean include)     at System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.XsltLoader.LoadStylesheet(XmlReader reader, Boolean include)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.XsltLoader.LoadStylesheet(XmlReader reader, Boolean include)     at S                        ystem.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.XsltLoader.Load(Compiler compiler, Object stylesheet, XmlResolver xmlResolver)     at System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.Compiler.Compile(Object stylesheet, XmlResolver xmlResolver, QilExpression& qil)     at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.LoadInternal(Object stylesheet, XsltSettings settings, XmlResolver stylesheetResolver)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.LoadXslCompiledTransform(WSSXmlUrlResolver someXmlResolver)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.GetXslCompiledTransform()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PrepareAndPerformTransform(Boolean bDeferExecuteTransform) 0d302e9f-581c-50ed-c97e-cad34f734763

Web Parts   89a2    High    InnerException 1: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()     at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetNonFileStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)     at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WSSXmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)     at System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.XsltLoader.CreateReader(Uri uri, XmlResolver xmlResolver)     at System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.XsltLoader.LoadStylesheet(Uri uri, Boolean include)     at System.Xml.Xsl.Xslt.XsltLoader.LoadStylesheet(XmlReader reader, Boolean include)  0d302e9f-581c-50ed-c97e-cad34f734763

High    Leaving Monitored Scope: (DataBinding DataFormWebPart (Quick Links)) Execution Time=269.318634528635; CPU Milliseconds=30; SQL Query Count=11; Parent=Request (GET:https://insight.company.com/Departments/PMO/Pages/default.aspx)  0d302e9f-581c-50ed-c97e-cad34f734763

Answer (score 0):

Try to deactivate and re-activate the publishing feature and test the scenario If that doesn't fix please share the ULS log for the mentioned correlation id.

Comment: The thing is, I can check this issue only once a day. I have done de- and re -activation. I have checked the log file, find accees issue with xsl file. I have updated the question with a part from log file. The particular user has "read" permission to style library and to its contents. 


The confusing thing is, If the system account log in once, then the particular users will have no issue, even if the system account logs out.

Comment: Once I provide _contribute_ permission for all users to **"XSL Stylesheets"** folder  residing in **Style Library**, this issue got **solved**. But this is not recommended to provide contribute permission to all users.